# How do I print out an hourglass using asterisks?

Tags: java

For a homework assignment, I am trying to construct a program that prints an hourglass shape to the screen using asterisks and spaces. I have written the program below, but its output doesn't look anything like an hourglass. Can anyone help me understand why my program isn't producing the expected output?

```
public class hourglass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int k = 2 * x - 1;
        int c = k;

        for (int j = x; j > 0; j--) {
            for (int f = j; f <= k; f++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int o = 1; o <= c; o++) {
                if (k % 2 == 0) System.out.print(" ");
                else System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I redid the program now it just prints into infinity and beyond, I understand the logic that I need to take in a x number and then run a for loop, each and every time I go through it I -1 from the x. 
Can anyone help me with this please? I'm simply trying to deepen my understanding in Java.

```
public class hourglass
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    int valueIn = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
    int maxVALUE = 2*valueIn ;

    for( int i = 0 ;  (valueIn - 1) > i; i--)
    {for( int j =1 ; j < maxVALUE; i++)
      {

      System.out.print("*");}
  for (int o = 1; o < maxVALUE; o++) {
    if (maxVALUE % 2 == 0) System.out.print(" ");
    else System.out.print(" ");
   }
   System.out.print("\n");




  }
 }
}
```

EDIT 2* 
If anyone sees this well, here I go.
I've constructed a code on my own for the past 8 hours and now I'm stuck, I don't know how I can "reverse" my for loop to make it print into the other direction here's my code, I don't know what to do and if anyone can give me any insight on how to do this I would be very pleased, I tried doing an if case if(i == 0) but that never happens and I even tried making that if case ==1; but then the loop ran forever.
Any pointers on how to finish my program?

```
public class mathrandom
{
  public static void main ( String [] args) 
  {
    int valueIn = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);


    for ( int i = valueIn;  1  <= i; i--){
      for ( int k = i ; k < 2*valueIn -1; k++)
      {System.out.print(" ");}
      {for ( int j = 1; j <= (i*2)-1; j++)
        {
        System.out.  print("*");


      }

        System.out.println();  
    }

}


  }}
```

Comment: You need to choose a better title. Your current one isn't very helpful.

Comment: You will stand a better chance of avoiding being eaten (and of getting a useful answer) if you learn [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your title and choose a better one which actually describes what your issue is. Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you know [how to ask on topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Josef, Poorly-formatted code is very difficult to read.  Whereas I appreciate you adding the missing closing braces, you do not help yourself by in the process clobbering the reformatting I performed for you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Better?

Comment: @Josef, yes, better.

Comment: I know this isn't CodeReview.SE, but do yourself (and us) a favor and use variable names that mean something. `x`,`k`,`c`,`j`,`o`? You can use names like `topWidth`, `baseWidth`, `height`. You can reuse an increment variable like `i` for the for loops - or call it something like `width`. Just some ideas that will make writing/reading your code a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't think in code (and what novice does?), you can try starting by writing a prose(-ish) description of how your program will go about its task, and then writing code that matches up to the prose.  For example, you might start with:

> Given an input `x` representing the width of an hourglass shape, print the hourglass to the screen as a series of lines containing asterisks and spaces.  The number of asterisks on each line will start at `x`, count down by two per line until a line containing fewer than two asterisks, then count back up by two per line until it reaches `x` again.  An appropriate number of leading spaces will be printed on each line to center that line's run of asterisks relative to the other lines' (assuming spaces are displayed with the same width as asterisks).

You can even put that into your source code as a comment.  In fact, it can help to break it up into several smaller comments, so that you can follow each logical thought with code that corresponds specifically to that thought.  If you do that, then not only does it help you organize your code, but you end up with a nicely-documented program without any extra effort.

If you compare my prose to your program, you should see both similarities and differences.  Your program performs some kind of count-down, at each step printing zero or more space characters, some asterisks, and then a newline to end the line.  Those are basically the right things for it to do, but the details are wrong.  Enough wrong and oddly enough wrong, in fact, that I'm inclined to suspect that the program is more cribbed from external sources than thoughtfully constructed *de novo*.  I suggest from here out you devote your attention to *writing* the program yourself.  In fact, consider starting by tossing out everything in `main()` except `int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`.